# Can I create new Selenium ChromeDriver instance from an opened ChromeDriver.exe?

Tags: c#, selenium

Firstly, sorry for my poor English.

I have a c# WCF restful service on which I use Selenium to send Whatsapp messages over "Whatsapp Web".

My problem is that I have to reopen the browser with every request to the WCF service.
Since, WCF restful is stateless, every request creates new service object on the server, resulting in creating new ChromeDriver instance and open the browser again.
If I don't call "chromedriver.Quit()" before completing the request, the browser remains opened. So, can I reuse that already opened browser instead running new instance of the browser with each request to the service?

I hope I could explain my question in a proper way.

Thanks in advance